# Datagridview taking more time to load in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I am getting data table(dtjr) value from stored procedure quickly,
but to assign this value to datagridview its taking more than 1 minute to load (65000 rows)
my code is

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = dtjr;
```

and in properties i added checkbox column,how load datatable value to datagridview faster.

Comment: Well, what's a minute with the time the user will need to read all those rows? - Seriously, this is too much, imo. One way to deal with this amount of data is DGV [virtual mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx) - Also for good scrolling make sure to double-buffer the dgv.

Comment: It's hard to tell without any code what is bottle neck in your case.
have you tried with `SuspendLayout`? Suspend, load, resume - like this: `dataGridView2.SuspendLayout();dataGridView2.DataSource = dtjr;dataGridView2.ResumeLayout();` Other than that, you should implement some paging...

Comment: Do you have some handlers for `DataGridView` events? For example: `CellFormatting` or `RowPrePaint`